# How to style this HTML input/div field?

Tags: html, css

I was asked in an exercise to make an input with the style exactly as shown in the image.

I'm having difficulties, can anyone help me? I want to get exactly the same design, but I'm having a hard time turning it into an input and everything in the right places.

[image: styled search box]

```css
#grupo_1 {
 top: 84px;
 left: 1381px;
 width: 219px;
 height: 32px;
}

#ret_ngulo_1 {
 opacity:0.10000000149012;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 width: 219px;
 height: 32px;
 -ms-border-radius: 16px;
 -o-border-radius: 16px;
 -moz-border-radius: 16px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 16px;
 border-radius: 16px;
 background:rgba(73,129,194,255);
}

#search_input {
 top: 7px;
 left: 14px;
 width: 78px;
 height: 18px;
}

#search___ {
 top: -3px;
 left: 26px;
 width: 57px;
 height: 21px;
 font-family: Noto Sans;
 font-size: 13px;
 text-align: left;
 color:#4d4f5c;
}

#icon_search {
 top: 1px;
 left: 0px;
 width: 16px;
 height: 16px;
}

#icon_search_ek1 {
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 width: 16px;
 height: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div id="grupo_1"  >
 <div id="ret_ngulo_1"  ></div>
 <div id="search_input"  >
  <div id="search___" >
   Search...
  </div>
  <div id="icon_search"  >
   <img src="https://i.imgur.com/LVbiP6D.png" id="icon_search_ek1" />
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems like a homework. Please provide further information following this paragraph from SO Help Center : Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Comment: No, it's my own initiative that I decided to work on, but I'm having initial difficulties.

Comment: This should be an input field like `<input type="text" placeholder="Search...">` (or `type="search"`) if you want to be able to type in it. Then you can add the magnifying glass icon as a background image.

Comment: @Dinho then remove "I was asked in an exercise to make an input with the style exactly as shown in the image." from your question to avoid ambiguity :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to play around with `display` and `position`. First you'll want to add `position: absolute` to `#ret_ngulo_1` to move the `Search` into the bar. After this you'll want to add `display: inline-block` to both `#search___` and `#icon_search`, along with *swapping* their order in the HTML. You may also want to play around with `margin`, though I haven't done so in this example.

```css
#grupo_1 {
  top: 84px;
  left: 1381px;
  width: 219px;
  height: 32px;
}

#ret_ngulo_1 {
  opacity: 0.10000000149012;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 219px;
  height: 32px;
  -ms-border-radius: 16px;
  -o-border-radius: 16px;
  -moz-border-radius: 16px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 16px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  background: rgba(73, 129, 194, 255);
  position: absolute;
}

#search_input {
  top: 7px;
  left: 14px;
  width: 78px;
  height: 18px;
}

#search___ {
  top: -3px;
  left: 26px;
  width: 57px;
  height: 21px;
  font-family: Noto Sans;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: left;
  color: #4d4f5c;
  display: inline-block;
}

#icon_search {
  top: 1px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#icon_search_ek1 {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div id="grupo_1">
  <div id="ret_ngulo_1"></div>
  <div id="search_input">
    <div id="icon_search">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/LVbiP6D.png" id="icon_search_ek1" />
    </div>
    <div id="search___">
      Search...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that you could also use the `<input>` tag directly, which would allow you to set the image as a background.

Also note `top` and `left` will only work on an element that is positioned (one that has an ancestor with `position` set), and that high `px` units won't render well on small devices.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but how do you transform this and use it as a text box?

Answer (score 0):

So, you could always give this slightly different approach a go!

See: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4ug31c2L/1/)

It requires a **lot less** wrapped classes & doesn't use the `Imgur` image you've listed, instead uses an `icon set` called Font Awesome. You can learn about Font Awesome [here](https://fontawesome.com/).

This is my example, along with how to reference the `icon set`:

```css
.search_box {
   border-radius: 15px;
   background-color: #edf3f9;
   opacity: 0.8;
   border: none;
   height: 20px;
   line-height: 20px;
   color: black;
   text-indent: 40px;
   width: 200px;
   position: relative;
}

.search_box::placeholder{   
   opacity: 0.9;
   color: black;
}

.search_box::-webkit-input-placeholder{   
   opacity: 0.9;
   color: black;
}

.search_box:-ms-input-placeholder{
   opacity: 0.9;
   color: black;
}

#search_icon {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99;
  left: 30px;
   opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div>
 <i class="fa fa-search" id="search_icon"></i>
 <input type="text" class="search_box" placeholder="Search..."/> 
</div>
```

Essentially, all my code does is:

1. List `Font Awesome`'s icon set as an external reference, you can see how to do this [here](https://www.w3schools.com/icons/fontawesome5_intro.asp)
2. Have a tag containing the icon, the icon is referenced by class, you can see all `Font Awesome` icons [here](https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery)
3. Create an `input` tag to be your `textbox`
4. Style this accordingly with `border-radius` and `opacity`
5. Ensure the `<i>` tag has a `z-index` higher than the `textbox` such that it is on top
6. Ensure the `textbox` and `<i>` tag have `position:relative` such that they are not impacted if you have elements above them
7. Do some basic alignment so that the search icon sits in the correct position in the searchbox

Goodluck with it! Even if you don't implement this, hopefully it's informative :)

Comment: That's cool! I literally use `Font Awesome` for everything.. it's such a good resource :D

Answer (score 0):

```css
/* Reset */
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* For demo */
body {
  padding: 20px;
}

/* Input */
.input {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  border: 2px solid #f1f1f1;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  transition: all .15s ease-in-out;
}

.input:focus {
  outline: none;
  border-color: #256dd3;
}

.input--search {
  padding-left: 36px;
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/LVbiP6D.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 12px center;
}
```

```html
<input class="input input--search" type="search" placeholder="Search...">
```

Very easy...

https://codepen.io/seanstopnik/pen/b7d2731bc0789d676a65fa08dc92e570